# Should I split a large file before running multiple regexes?

Tags: java, regex

I have an input that's about 35KB of text that I need to pull a bunch of small bits of data from.  I use multiple regexes to find the data, and that part works fine.

My question: should I split the large text into multiple smaller strings and run the appropriate regexes on each string, or just keep it in one big string and reset the matcher for each regex?  Which way is best for efficiency?

Comment: Post you regex parsing code then only we can tell you if improvements can be made in it.

Comment: Does the file have multiple smaller lines of input, or is it one big chunk of 35KB?

Comment: Is this causing you a problem? Do you _know_ that it is a bottleneck?

Comment: It's a big text document that I pull small bits of data out of subsections, section A might have 5 chunks of data, section B 10, section C 7, and so on.  I guess my question really is how much does the length of the input string affect the performance of regex searches?

Comment: Until someone with a concrete knowledge on this specific case writes here, you can try to benchmark both approaches. Since you mentioned your code works already, it should not be hard.

Comment: Are you saying that some of the regex do not have to be run on some parts of the file?

Comment: I didn't even consider benchmarking it, I'll do that, thanks.  Yes, each regex only applies to a small section of the file and will never match anything outside that section.

Comment: Split the file and run only the relevant regex. Running a regex unnecessarily on a 35KB file is extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it isn't running too slow then go with whatever you currently have that is working fast enough.

Otherwise, you shouldn't be using raw regexes for this task anyway. As soon as you mention "multiple regexes" extracting "small bits of data" from, you are talking about writing a parser and should use a decent parsing tool.

As you are using java I would recommend starting with [jFlex](http://jflex.de/), which is a mature java implementation of an extremely mature and stable C tool.

For most tasks jFlex will be all you need, but it also integrates smoothly with a number of java parser-generators should the problem prove to be more complicated. My personal preference is the slightly obscure [Beaver](http://beaver.sourceforge.net/).

Of course, if you can implement it as a set of regexes it isn't more complicated and jFlex will do the job for you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with lexical analyzers at all, but don't they require a pattern in the input?  My input data is more like a written document than a structured language, there is no formatting repetition.  Each regex matches only once and each regex is different.

Comment: Lexical analyzers are just a way of matching a large number of regexes concurrently and optionally returning some 'token' derived from a match. With a stateful lexer, such as JFlex, you can also group your regexes into 'states' and switch between them in response to a match. From the description you give, it sounds like JFlex is a perfect match to your problem (if you will forgive the unavoidable pun). A regular grammar parser is a common addition, but that does require a structured language; however, you can also use statistical parser from a natural-language-processing toolkit.

Comment: Finally switched to JFlex and it works great, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. JFlex is one of my favourite "secret" java tools. To the extent I probably switch from regex to lexer too quickly these days. Regardless, it is a very powerful tool, and well rewards any time spent learning it.